# PHP preg_match get string inside double quotes for WordPress syntax

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-replace, preg-match-all

I’m using `preg_match_all` single quotes `'` in my WordPress syntax code highlight and it **is working**

```
preg_match_all("/'(.*?)'/",$content,$matches);
```

But when I’m using double quotes `"` with this code, it **is not working**

```
preg_match_all('/"(.*?)"/',$content,$matches);
```

Is there a simple way to fix the code?

--edit--

i'm using this code for make my own plugin for wordpress syntax highlight code

```
function myHighlightSyntaxCode($content ) 
{
   global $post;
   $content= $post->post_content;                          
   $content=reformatText($content);
   return $content;
}
function reformatText($content){

   preg_match_all("/'(.*?)'/",$content,$matches);
   /*
     this is the part of my code for content inside quote
   */

}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'myHighlightSyntaxCode');
```

Comment: Can you show us examples of `$content` and what you expect to find in `$matches`?

Comment: yes, you can see on my blog to see :)

http://blog.imammubin.com/php-class-database-connection-construct-function-class-by-subclass/2014/02/05/

Answer (score 1):

Do like this negate the quotes inside the matches

```
preg_match_all('/"([^"]*)"/',$content,$matches);
```